# Jquery autocompletion json fun

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I just started working with Jquery UI autocompletion.
The way I intend to make it work is through JSON data.

As it is now I am going to get quiet a few thousand JSON entries that all look like this:

```
{
"FirstName": "Name",
"LastName": "Surname",
"Initials": "mtg",
"EmploymentDescription": "Udbudskonsulent"
},
```

now, i need the autocompete to help limit the amount of search results based on the "initials" value.
Unfortunately the autocompete only sorts the values after label, value and id keys, meaning that if i renamed "Initials" to one of those values it should fix the problem. 
Unfortunately that is not an option so I need another way to make the autocompleter to work the way i want to.

So, any of you guys have an suggestion to get the autocompleter to help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i get the question, correct me if  i am wrong, user is going to search by typing **mtg**

Changing the JSON snippet as follows(*for eg*.).

```
   {
"FirstName": "Micheal",
"LastName": "TobiasGrey",
"Initials": "mtg",
"EmploymentDescription": "StackOverflowGuy"
},
```

**Micheal TobiasGrey** should be rendered in the list.(assuming the relation between mtg and Michael is established at server side)

We can make the autocomplete widget *see* our custom results as its own label and value as follows.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url : "/CCInfoHandlerServlet",
data : param,
dataType : 'json',
success :function( data)
{

        response($.map(data,function(item){


            return {
                    value : item.FirstName+""+item.LastName,//This will be displayed in ur text field after selection
                    label : item.FirstName+""+item.LastName, //This will be displayed in ur suggestion list

                 };

            }));//response method ends- this passes the data

},//Success ends
```